# Jquery - appending ajax received content along with preloader

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a function for my cms that works like popular infinite scroll wordpress plugin. It loads next pages from db when I scroll to bottom of the page and appends them.

First it counts elements existing inside page list:

```
var $number = $(".pages-3 li").length;
```

Number is passed as parameter to php in order to fetch next page content from database:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"ajax.php",  
    data: { number: $number},
    beforeSend:function(){
    $(".pages-3").append('<li>LOADING</li>');},
    success:function(data) {
    $(".pages-3 li:nth-last-of-type(1)").html(data);
}
```

However there is a problem. I wanted to add preloader, so before ajax start i already add list item to list. Then i would replace this item content with actual page content.

List items are counted before appending preloader list item. So theoretically script should always provide right number of list positions.

Yet only first time number is correct. 
Then number is larger by 2 and than larger by 3. I dont really understand why.

Comment: It's difficult to say, But you have appended `$(".pages-3").append('<li>LOADING</li>')` loading `li` you need to remove it in `success`!

Comment: maybe `$(".pages-3 li:first-child").html(data);` can help. Well you have only one `li` element, so just `$(".pages-3 li").html(data);` should work.

Comment: What does `data` look like? Is it wrapped in `li` tags? Then that is the problem. jQuerys `.html()` only changes *inner* HTML, so you will get an `li` in an `li` for every item you add. Remove the wrapping tags, and change the selector to `.page-3 > li...` so it doesnt match any lower level `li` elements.

Comment: An alternative is to remove the preloader and append the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) in your success callback,

```
success:function(){
    $(".pages-3 li:contains(LOADING)").html(data);
}
```

Alternatively you can use [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) like

```
success:function(){
    $(".pages-3 li:last-child").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Since your count is off by one for every list item you add, it sounds like the data you add contains list items. For instance, if the variable `data` is already wrapped in `li` tags you will get nested tags (`<li><li>Content</li></li>`) since jQuerys `.html()` works on the *inner* HTML of the element.

To avoid this, use `>` to only match *direct* descendants like this:

```
var $number = $(".pages-3 > li").length;
```

To avoid mixing the preloader with the actual content (and make your code clearer) you can give it a class to indicate that it is a preloader. For obvious reasons, let's call it `preloader`:

```
 $(".pages-3").append('<li class="preloader">LOADING</li>');
```

Then, when you count the elements, exclude elements with the class `preloader`:

```
var $number = $(".pages-3 > li:not(.preloader)").length;
```

Finally, remove the class when the content is actually loaded:

```
$(".pages-3 > li.preloader").html(data).removeClass("preloader");
```